# When is the limit computable in the sense of computable analysis?

Tags: computability-theory

Assume a function $f(x,y)$ over the real numbers that is computable in the sense of computable analysis. Let $g(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty}f(x,y)$. I have two questions:

1) Under what conditions does $g(x)$ exist?

2) Assume $g(x)$ exist? Is it always computable? If not, then under what conditions it is computable?

Comment: How about functions such as $f(m,n)=1$ if TM $m$ has stopped after $n$ steps, and $f=0$ otherwise? (This isn't real arguments, but I guess it could be adapted.)

Comment: Question 1 is much too vague.  What are you looking for?  This is probably a better question for Math Stack Exchange. However, to be clear, that limit $g(x)$ need not exist, and if it exists it need not be a computable function.  To show it need not exist, just pick any standard function $f(x,y)$ such that $\lim_y f(x,y)$ diverges for all $x$.  Such an example is likely computable.  Next, find an example such that $\lim_y f(x,y)$ converges for all $x$, but $g(x) := lim_y f(x,y)$ is not continuous.  Again, $f(x,y)$ is likely computable, but $g(x)$ can't be computable since it is not continuous.

Comment: I should probably explain why (1) is too vague.  Since computable analysis mirrors actual analysis, your question is basically asking "under what conditions does $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exist for a continuous function $f$?".  There is no reasonable answer except to give a definition of "convergence" (say using $\varepsilon$'s and $\delta$'s).

Comment: Pour El and Richard's book,  available freely here: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422916#toc is a good source for these questions.